# How to delay the execution of code without using a new thread in Android

Tags: android, delay

In Eclipse, I found that using a TimeLine and a KeyFrame I can delay the execution of code, for example, to wait 4 seconds before playing a media I used this code:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
KeyFrame keyframe = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(4000), DelayAnimation ->
{
    GeneralMethods PlayMusic = new GeneralMethods();
    PlayMusic.playMusic(mediaPlayer);
});

timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyframe);
timeline.play();
```

The previous code works fine in Eclipse and I did not need to create a new thread.

My question is, Is there a similar way to delay the execution of code in Android?

I found a way to delay the execution of code, but it is using a handler, that is to say, creating a new thread. I would like to delay without using a thread, is it possible?

Comment: A Handler does not create a new Thread....

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handler is what you use to delay something in your thread. In the following case, the handler makes your UI TextView disappear after waiting for ten seconds;

```
private void makeTextViewDisappear(){
yourTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   yourTV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         // OR yourTV.setVisibility(View.GONE) to reclaim the space 
                }
            }, 10000);
}
```

As you can see, there is no new thread.

Comment: Thank you. The code I found was using a new Thread, but in your code I can see there is not one, just the runnable managed by the handler. I was just wondering if there is an alternative to the handler, or is the handler the only way to insert a delay?

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.sleep(10000)`

It will delay your current thread by 10 secs

Comment: Would you really want to do this on the main thread?

Comment: Thank you Girish. I used the sleep method as my first attempt, but it did not work. I was wondering if there is an alternative in Android as the TimeLine and KeyFrame